# Ejecutar un archivo PHP desde una funcion public

Tags: php

tengo estos dos archivos.
Uno es una funciona que me inserta datos en la base la otra un envio de mail usando php mailer.
Funcion que inserta:

```
<?php

class MvcBug{


public function nuevoReporteBugController($tabla, $redireccionamiento){

    if (isset($_POST["bugReport"])) {
        $dato = $_POST["bugReport"];
        $dato = trim($dato);
        $respuesta = MvcControllerBug::nuevoReporteBugModel($dato, $tabla, $redireccionamiento, $_SESSION["idUsuario"]);
        unset($_POST['bugReport']);
    }
}
```

}

Y la salida del email:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'mail/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "············";
$mail->Password = "············";
$mail->setFrom('...............', '...........');
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'Base');
$mail->addAddress("..........", "...........");

$mail->Subject = "Prueba";
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__);
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
$mail->send();
?>
```

Ambos archivos archivos funcionan por separado al ejecutarlos, como podria hacer para que al momento que la funcion inserte los datos y obtenga las $respuesta , se ejecute el archivo del email para que ademar de insertar me avise por email que ese cambio fue hecho?

Comment: ¿El código de envío del email está en el mismo archivo que la función `nuevoReporteBugController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías mandar el mail desde otro método

```
<?php
require_once 'mail/autoload.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

class MvcBug{


    public function nuevoReporteBugController($tabla, $redireccionamiento){

        if (isset($_POST["bugReport"])) {
            $dato = $_POST["bugReport"];
            $dato = trim($dato);
            unset($_POST['bugReport']);
            try {
                $respuesta = MvcControllerBug::nuevoReporteBugModel($dato, $tabla, $redireccionamiento, $_SESSION["idUsuario"]);
                $this->_enviarMail();
            } catch (\Exception $e {
              echo 'No se pudo insertar el registro' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    private function _enviarMail() {
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "············";
        $mail->Password = "············";
        $mail->setFrom('...............', '...........');
        $mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'Base');
        $mail->addAddress("..........", "...........");

        $mail->Subject = "Prueba";
        $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__);
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
        $mail->send();
    }
}
```

Si te fijas, además envuelvo la inserción en un bloque try/catch para evitar el envío del mail si la inserción falla. Además, debieras comprobar si el mail se envió, me imagino que capturando la salida de  `$mail->send()`, pero ignoro si PHPMailer tira una excepción o devuelve un mensaje de error cuando no logra el envío.

Por otro lado, en tu código no aparece de dónde obtienes `MvcControllerBug`. Si estás usando composer (y debieras) entonces la primera línea debiera llamar a `vendor/autoload.php` en vez de usar el autoloader de PHPMailer que es sólo un sustituto puntual. De esa manera, si `MvcControllerBug` está en el mismo namespace que `MvcBug` no necesitarías incluir el código de éste en la clase que nos muestras.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciona todo perfecto